# Symfony: how to pass config parameters of reusable bundle to framework/twig?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm creating reusable Symfony bundle that has many configuration parameters and I need them in framework and twig bundles also.

Here is a working example of how my config currently looks (app/config/config.yml):

```
# my bundle parameters
parameters:
  locales_active:
    - en_US
    - de_DE
  locale_default: en_US
  locale_fallback: de_DE
  google_maps_api_key: some_value
  google_translate_api_key: some_value

# framework parameters
framework:
  translator:      { fallbacks: ['%locale_fallback%']
  default_locale:  "%locale_default%"

# twig parameters
twig:
  globals:
    locales_active: '%locales_active%'
    google_maps_api_key: '%google_maps_api_key%'
    google_translate_api_key: '%google_translate_api_key%'
```

This approach works, but I want to be as simple as possible to install this bundle (here is only a small part of parameters, actually there are many more).

**What I would like to do is:**

1) only create this part of code in config.yml (move bundle parameters to it's own namespace from global "parameters:"):

```
acme_core:
  locales_active:
    - en_US
    - de_DE
  locale_default: en_US
  locale_fallback: de_DE
  google_maps_api_key: some_value
  google_translate_api_key: some_value
```

2) assign these parameters to framework or twig dynamically without editing configuration file. For example, maybe in DependencyInjection/Configuration.php if that is possible.

How this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to achieve. Just play around with it.

You need to use DependencyInjection/Configuration and AcmeCoreExtension.

1. Configuration file should contain validation params and the structure of your bundle's configuration.
2. AcmeCoreExtension should merge your config with twig.

> ```
> public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
> {
>     $configuration = new Configuration();
>
>     $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
>
>     // merge your configs here (or something similar)
>     // $config['twig']['globals']['locales_active'] = 
> }
> ```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html